# NullPointerException while Mocking jersey get method using Mockito

Tags: java, junit, jersey, mockito, powermock

So, I am trying to mock a jersey get method and to some extent my test case is working fine but it throws `NPE` when it gets to get(Response.class) method. I've spent a lot of time but couldn't figure out.

Method under test (a few lines)

```
DocusignRESTClient client = (DocusignRESTClient) AppContext.getBean("restServiceClient");
        WebTarget resourcePing = client.createResource( ESignatureSpringUtil.getMessage( KeyConstants.ALSB_DOCUSIGN_ADDRESS )
                + ESignatureSpringUtil.getMessage( KeyConstants.REST_PING_VENDOR_ADDRESS ) );

        Response response = resourcePing
            .request()
            .accept( MediaType.APPLICATION_XML )
            .header( KeyConstants.REST_URI_APPENDERS, pingSb )
            .header( DocusignRESTContants.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
            .header( DocusignRESTContants.X_DOCUSIGN_AUTHENTICATION, getDocusignAuthHeader( cu ) )
            .get( Response.class );
```

Test Case

```
@Test
public void testPingVendor() throws Exception, DocusignRESTClientException {
    accountId = "025f1a5d-b796-4ba6-85d2-b2a4a90d109c";
    address = "docusignRestAddress";

    AppContext.setApplicationContext( applicationContext );
    iClientUserDto.setClientUserVendor( iClientUserVendorDto );
    DocusignRESTProvider docusignRestProvider = new DocusignRESTProvider();
    docusignRestProvider.setLoggingHandler( iloggingHandler );

    PowerMockito.when( DtoUtils.lookupClientUserVendorParam( any( String.class ), Mockito.anyListOf( IClientUserVendorParamDto.class ) ) ).thenReturn( accountId );
    PowerMockito.when( ESignatureSpringUtil.getMessage( any( String.class ) ) ).thenReturn( address );
    PowerMockito.when( AppContext.getBean( any( String.class ) ) ).thenReturn( docusignRestClient );
    PowerMockito.when( DocusignRESTUtil.getDocusignAuthHeader( iClientUserDto ) ).thenReturn( "authProvider" );

    when( docusignRestClient.createResource( any( String.class ) ) ).thenReturn( webTarget );
    when( webTarget.request() ).thenReturn( builder );
    when( webTarget.request().accept( any( MediaType.class ) ) ).thenReturn( builder );
    when( webTarget.request().accept( any( MediaType.class ) ).header( any( String.class ), anyObject() ) ).thenReturn( builder );
    when( webTarget.request().accept( any( MediaType.class ) ).header( any( String.class ), anyObject() ).get( Response.class ) ).thenReturn( response );

    docusignRestProvider.pingVendor( iClientUserDto );
```

stack trace:

```
java.security.ProviderException
at com.mercuryinsurance.esignature.integration.provider.docusign.rest.DocusignRESTProvider.pingVendor(DocusignRESTProvider.java:204)
at test.com.mercuryinsurance.esignature.integration.provider.docusign.rest.TestDocusignRESTProvider.testPingVendor(TestDocusignRESTProvider.java:89)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:66)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:86)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:94)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:106)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
... 31 more
```

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth I know what is NPE but here the third party library is involved and I am not sure what is causing this. Please don't mark duplicate if you don't know the answer.

Comment: But the process for identifying the cause is always the same.  Debug, step through, etc. until you've hit the line that throws the underlying error, then work backwards.

Comment: Do you think I haven't done those steps. Look at the get method which returns Response object. It is all in one line you can't even put a break point. For each method I have a mock method invocation.

That one is the custom object. You haven't even read the question man. This is Jersey rest implementation. So simple to mark duplicate without even seeing anything.

Comment: You could split it into multiple statements.  Or break immediately before, and then step through.

Comment: break before what?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you meant by "it's all on one line" to mean the `resourcePing.accept(...)...` line.  Either way, this is basically impossible for anyone to help with currently, because you've only pasted part of your method-under-test, part of your test code (what is e.g. `response`?), and there's not enough information to tell what part is actually throwing the exception(s).  I suggest boiling this down to a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Method is really long and it got so many layers. It is blowing right in the get part. Response is the jersey Class.